# Sencha Touch 2 Store - Modify response before creating models

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

In Backbone.js you can add a "parse" method to your "collections" to modify the response object before models are created. Is this possible with a Sencha Touch Store? I've gone through the docs but can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A few things really... one thing is that the response I get back has a nested namespace and the "root" config property seems to only accept a top level object property. I also need to merge a few objects with the objects that are to be turned into models.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use nested roots (specify something like `results.level1.root`. As for adding additional logic - I think you will have to look ar how they do parsing and may be extend standard class with your logic - I don't remember anything built-in for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably over write the read Ext.data.data.Reader

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/source/Reader.html#Ext-data-reader-Reader

Which is where it handles the raw data and plays with it ( and finally returns a model )